# Running log operation in Http Modules?

Tags: httpmodule

I have a simple requirement in which I want to execute a long running application program on server (e.g. DTSX) I want to make an HTTP module for this, But I have a question whether the DTSX will run even if the user closes the page and browser.
In my case user hits the handler with a query string but what if the user closes the browser immediately? How is the behavior different from simple linear page processing?

I want my DTSX package to finish once its started no matter how much time it takes and also dont want to halt the user that is why I am using http modules in place of linear asp page processing.

Reagrds,
Niranjan

Answer (score 0):

Run your DTSX as a seperate service and pass requests to it via a backend call. That way once your request has been sent to the module it doesn't matter what the calling page does.